# Query: Find the earliest date with a null entry which still works with no null entries

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am building a query that displays the next due date for users. The number of dates stays the same, but the due date will change, depending on how many records have a comment from the user.

```
SELECT tbl_Description.Sample, 
       tbl_Description.User, 
       Min(tbl_Data.TestDate) As DueDate
  FROM tbl_Description 
 INNER 
  JOIN tbl_Data 
    ON tbl_Description.DescriptionID = tbl_Data.DateID
 WHERE tbl_Data.Comment IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY tbl_Description.Sample, 
       tbl_Description.User;
```

However, when every record from `tbl_Data` has a comment, the query returns empty records. This may happen because the `WHERE` and `IS NULL` statement returns nothing if every record exists. Preferably, I would still like the null record to appear with something in the `[DueDate]` field, such as a blank or “Complete” comment.

**tbl_Description**

```
Sample          User
1               Betty
```

**tbl_Data (v1)**

```
Date          Comments
05/01/2018    Orange
05/08/2018    Orange-Brown
05/15/2018
05/22/2018
```

**Query Output**

```
Sample          User          DueDate
1               Betty         05/15/2018
```

**tbl_Data (v2)**

```
Date          Comments
05/01/2018    Orange
05/08/2018    Orange-Brown
05/15/2018    Brown
05/22/2018    Brown-Black
```

**Query Output (Query returns nothing at the moment)**

```
Sample          User          DueDate
1               Betty         Complete
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post some sample data with an expectation of the final result?

Comment: Sorry! Added some context to original post - hope that helps.

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN to join your tables. Use NVL to convert an empty minimum TestDate to whatever you want to show.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `WHERE` clause returns an empty set, so `NVL` or `NZ` will have no effect on the `SELECT` statement

Comment: Do you really want one record per Sample/User or is it rather one record per DescriptionID?

Comment: It should be one record per DescriptionID... I was just too lazy to include it in the table example, but the Sample # should serve the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now knowing that we also can group by `DescriptionID`, I suggest to query the minimum `TestDate` for records from `tbl_Data` without a `Comment` separately and (outer) join the result to the table `tbl_Description`. This way, each *Description* is contained in the result, and when all *Dates* for a *Description* have a `Comment`, the `DueDate` will appear blank:

```
SELECT tbl_Description.Sample, tbl_Description.User, Uncommented.DueDate
FROM tbl_Description 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT tbl_Data.DateID, Min(tbl_Data.TestDate) AS DueDate
        FROM tbl_Data
        WHERE (((tbl_Data.Comment) Is Null))
        GROUP BY tbl_Data.DateID
    ) AS Uncommented ON tbl_Description.DescriptionID = Uncommented.DateID;
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked great! This is my first time encountering this kind of SQL structure (I don't know much). Did you essentially create a subquery within the LEFT JOIN, and link it back to tbl_Description via the foreign key?

Comment: @Plaxerous Yes, that is essentially what I did. The subquery could also be saved as a separate query. It calculates the minimum `TestDate` per `DateID` where only records without a `Comment` are taken into account. In the main query, the *Descriptions* table could then be joined to this query so that all records from `tbl_Description` are returned. Doing it that way, both queries can be created without the *SQL view*, just using the graphical design window.